# Nextjs Link tag points to same page causes a Refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js

If the user is on the Home page, clicking on the Home Page option in the Header Menu will cause a refresh and loads the same page. Using `<Link as='/homepage' href='/landing'>Home Page</Link>` inside the Header Layout and also a custom server to server all the URL requests.

Comment: In your current implementation if you redirect other page will it refresh too?

Comment: What behaviour did you want to happen?

Comment: @tareqaziz Yes, added a Link tag inside` /pages/Firstpage` to go to home page `<Link as='/homepage' href='/landing'>Home Page</Link>` apart from the header Link tag.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning if the Current Page was Home Page, clicking on the Header Link tag to go to the Homepage should be disabled.

Comment: @visizky in that case just disable the link somehow

Comment: @tareqaziz doing so would prevent users from accessing the other pages.

Comment: @visizky basically I want to say once user reach to home page then disable otherwise make it accessible, are you able to put the whole component code?

Comment: To reproduce the issue faced, visit https://help.netflix.com/en/legal/termsofuse then scroll down to the Footer and click on Terms of Use. The page refreshes, I would like to stop the reload of the page if the user clicks Terms while already in Terms.

Comment: @tareqaziz I am wrapping all pages inside custom _app.js with a MyLayout component. How can I disable the Links that are inside the Header component based on the current page? Example

Comment: You can create a custom Link component, which will return Link (next js) if the href and router pathName doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same issue. For me it turned out to be bc I was using `getServerSideProps` in the page's index file. I was misusing it and was able to replace it with `getStaticProps`, instead. Might be a good idea to inspect which of nextjs data fetching functions you are using. (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching).