# why Redirect doesn't work if I don't reset the state?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Below is some code from a book:

```
export class ToggleLink extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            doRedirect: false
        }
    }

    handleClick = () => {
       this.setState({ doRedirect: true },
             () => this.setState({ doRedirect: false }));
    }

    render() {
        return <Route path={this.props.to} exact={this.props.exact}
            children={routeProps => {
                const baseClasses = this.props.className || "m-2 btn btn-block";
                const activeClass = this.props.activeClass || "btn-primary";
                const inActiveClass = this.props.inActiveClass || "btn-secondary"

                const combinedClasses =
                    `${baseClasses} ${routeProps.match ? activeClass : inActiveClass}`

                return <React.Fragment>
                    {this.state.doRedirect && <Redirect to={this.props.to} />}
                    <button className={combinedClasses} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </button>
                </React.Fragment>
            }} />
    }
}
```

and I'm using them as :

```
<ToggleLink to="/products">Products</ToggleLink>
<ToggleLink to="/suppliers">Suppliers</ToggleLink>
```

this works but I'm just wondering why we need to reset the state back to false, if I change the `handleCLick` handler as:

```
 this.setState({ doRedirect: true });
```

the the redirect doesn't work. For example, I'm in Product section and if I click the Suppliers button, it won't go to the suppliers section, why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AminPaks to use an alternative of NavLink

Comment: Are you just trying to redirect conditionally?

Comment: What do you want to do with this code `handleClick = () => {
       this.setState({ doRedirect: true },
             () => this.setState({ doRedirect: false }));
    }` ,  at 1st true then false?

Comment: @tareqaziz  the code is from an advance book, it shows an alternative approach of using Link/NavLink, you can copy/paster the code and try it you see what I mean. It won't work until the state has been reset to false

Answer (score 0):

I think you just change your handleClick like this way

```
handleClick = () => {
       this.setState({ doRedirect: true });
    }
```

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58989909/nextjs-link-tag-points-to-same-page-causes-a-refresh/58991562#58991562) also give you a basic idea about the routing in react

Comment: that's what I asked exactly. But it won't work, if you try the code you will see the link won't be high lighted when it is activated

Comment: If you need a working copy you can try my answer link, BTW can you please share that code/book url you tried to implement

Answer (score 0):

The resetting is in place so that you can *reuse* the redirect mechanism.

Notice that in your code, you only set the `doRedirect` value in one direct, i.e. from `false` to `true` upon the click of the button. And for the redirect mechanism, it depends on the flipping of the `doRedirect` value from `false` to `true` to trigger and complete the redirect, not the other way around. By removing the callback function in `setState`, the system never gets to be reset, so the redirect will only work once (for each button).

See a working code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-hermann-hcz8q. Notice how the `doRedirect` stucks at `true` after one click and the redirect stops working.